# How to always call the newest field of C# class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I've been baffled by a behavior of `new` keyword in C#, as it doesn't seem to completely override its parent value, here's an example:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A test = new B();

        Console.WriteLine(test.s);
    }

    public class A {

        public string s = "A";
    }

    public class B : A{
        public new string s = "B";
    }
```

Now here I expected "B" to be printed, but instead, I got "A"

How can I always call the new property, whatever class is renewing it,  instead of the original one?

Comment: There are no "properties" in the code you show.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think OP meant "fields".

Comment: yep, you're right, fixed it

Comment: Fields can not be overridden, only properties and methods can be overridden. You should never use fields outside the class. The proper way says, that all properties should be private *(you should not modify fields even from descendants)*. Use virtual property, or a protected setter.

Comment: @Meowxiik did any answer help you? If you have anything that you want to ask about the answers, please do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `new` keyword basically *hides* the member under a new member of the same name. However, this new member with the same name only exists on the subclass B and not on the base class A. So you wouldn't observe that `test.s` contains "B" unless you casted `test` to B first.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    A test = new B();

    Console.WriteLine(test.s); // A

    B test2 = test as B;

    Console.WriteLine(test2.s); // B
}

public class A 
{
    public string s = "A";
}

public class B : A
{
    public new string s = "B";
}
```

If you want the member to be *replaced*, then you have to use the `override` keyword. However, you cannot override fields, only methods and properties. Try this:

```
public class A
{
    protected virtual string s { get => "A"; }
}

public class B : A
{
    protected override string s { get => "B"; }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    A test = new B();

    Console.WriteLine(test.s); // will print B
}
```

The `virtual` keyword on `A.s` indicates that that property can be overridden.

Julo's comment correctly points out that it is bad form to try to modify fields from subclasses anyway. Generally, class fields should always be `private`.

Answer (score 2):

For methods and properties, you can do this by replacing `new` with `override`. `override` *actually* overrides the method, while `new` only hides it.

The same goes for fields, but you can't use `override` with fields.

But if you look closely, what you want here is to override the *initial* value of `s`. In both classes, `s` can be changed later on.

To change the initial value, just write a constructor:

```
public B() {
    s = "B";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As it's already been pointed out, the `new` keyword is only going to hide the value, not override it. To do that, you'd need to use the `override` keyword, which can't be used on fields, but it can be used on properties, like this:

```
public static Main(string[] args)
{
    A test = new B();
    Console.WriteLine(test.S);    // Prints "B"
}

public class A
{
    protected string s;
    public virtual string S { get => "A"; set => s = value; }
}
public class B : A
{
    public override string S { get => "B"; set => s = value; }
}
```

This is probably the closest to what you expected to happen, but we have to introduce the backing field to be able to change the value of `S`. If you don't plan on doing so, you can just use `public virtual string S => "A";` and making it a readonly.

However, this probably isn't the intended use of overriding properties. It's most likely there to do something different in the `get` or `set` functions like this:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual string S 
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
public class B : A
{
    public override string S
    {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Since all you're doing is changing the values, it's probably better to just do it in the constructor.

```
public class A
{
    public string S { get; set; } = "A";
}
public class B : A
{
    public B() => S = "B";
}
```

The downside of using the constructor is that, if you're changing the value for all the child classes, you're not gonna be able to quickly tell what the value is without opening up the constructor, which might make it harder to find. So, all in all, it's gonna come down to personal preference on which approach you use.